# ON DELETE CASCADE on pg_class in PostgreSQL does not work

Tags: postgresql

I added a foreign key on my table which references pg_class.

```
ALTER TABLE summary_table 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (table_oid_column) REFERENCES pg_class (oid) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I have a summary table which I keep some information about tables with their relational ids. When I drop a table I want to delete automatically related row from my summary table, so I added constraint above. But in my case, when I drop a table nothing happens.

I tried it with a test table, when I delete related row from test table, it works as expected. Such as with this foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE summary_table 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (table_oid_column) REFERENCES test (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

What can be the problem? Can it be related with being a catalog table(pg_class) or a hidden system column(oid)?

Comment: You cannot create foreign key references to a system table.

Comment: With this option: "allow_system_table_mods = on" I created.

Comment: Wow. What hack. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Assume that, I'm also willing to change source code. I want to understand underlying logic, and why this "hack" is not working.

Comment: And as I stated I want to delete related row(s) from my table upon dropping tables. I will be glad to hear new ideas about how to accomplish this in better ways.

Comment: Any error messsages?

Comment: No, neither in psql or postgres logfile (log_statement='all')

Answer (score 5):

Constraints are only checked when you execute SQL-level DML commands such as `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.  They are not checked when you effect a system catalog data change using a DDL command such as `DROP TABLE`.  Those take a different code path internally, even though they end up modifying the same data.

As a consequence, you currently cannot do what you are trying to do.  In PostgreSQL 9.3, there will be event triggers, which will address the space your problem is in.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU it will not work (at least in <9.2) because foreign key constraints are based on triggers and triggers are not implemented for system catalog tables.

[Some work](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/DDL_Triggers) is held in the direction of so called event triggers in the upcoming 9.3 so it will be possible to catch DDL events like CREATE, ALTER, DROP. However things are still [too limited](http://www.depesz.com/2012/07/29/waiting-for-9-3-event-triggers/).

Comment: I'm using 9.1.3, although it does not work as expected, I'm definitely able to create foreign key constraint as stated in comments of the question.

Comment: It possible will not produce any error but it will not be functional.

Comment: You might be right there, it would be good to have error messages.

Comment: I fully agree. I think it it worth mentioning in pgsql-general@postgresql.org or even pgsql-bugs@postgresql.org.